# Mail from Postfix not in "Sent" folder

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix

When I send an e-mail from my local computer from Thunderbird, all my e-mails show up in the "Sent" folder on the Fastmail website. But when I send an email from Postfix from my Ubuntu server the emails don't show up in the "Sent" folder. How can I change this?

Comment: You're comparing Thunderbird (a mail user agent, MUA) with postfix, which is an mail transport agent (MTA).
How are you creating that email being sent via postfix? Add this info to your question.

Comment: I don't compare Thunderbird with Postfix. I want to get the same effect on Postfix as on Thunderbird. After sending the email with Postfix, I want it to be added to the "Sent" folder on the Fastmail website. And I send the e-mail on the server like this:
sendmail -f "fromemial@example.com" tomail@example.com

Answer (score 0):

Sending a mail (with SMTP) and storing it in the Sent folder (with IMAP) are two different things, although most mail client does this concurrently.
There are very specific SMTP servers (best example is the gmail), who can store a copy of the sent mails in the "Sent" IMAP-Folder of the actual user, but this is an extraordinary feature and most server doesn't do this.

tl;dr sendmail can't do that, you'll need a setup that does both storing and sending your emails from the command line. mutt(1) for example could be configured to do such.